# How to upload nested files using multer?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I want to know the way of uploading multiple images using multipart/form-data when the required request body is nested as below. Currently I tried uploading images using **multer** with single key value pair and it's working fine. But, is there any alternative through which I can upload file to file_path property and send it to the backend.

```
{
    "Name": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Images": [{
            "field_name": "Field 1",
            "input": [{
                "type": "image",
                "file_path": "Uploading File"
            }]
        }
}
```